# Java : How to create dynamic JSON tree from database?

Tags: java, json, database, tree

I have a table in database with structure and data below :

[image]

I want to get the JSON tree data from that table through java :

```
[
   {
          "id":"null",
          "text":"Text1",
          "children":[
             {
                "id":3,
                "text":"Text3",
                "children":[

                ]
             },
             {
                "id":4,
                "text":"Text4",
                "children":[
                   {
                      "id":10,
                      "text":"Text10",
                      "children":[

                      ]
                   }
                ]
             },
             {
                "id":6,
                "text":"Text6",
                "children":[

                ]
             }
          ]
       },
       ...
    ]
```

**Can anybody help me out ?**

**Thanks in advance.** :)

Comment: learn about elastic search basics...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow my bellow steps:

1. Create a class for result

> ```
> public class NodeBean implements Serializable {
>      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>      private Integer id;
>      private String text;
>      private List children;
> }
> ```

2. Create a class for data-map from DB

> ```
> public class NodeInfoBean {
>      private Integer id;
>      private String text; 
> }
> ```

3. Write a method to get Data from DB by parentId:

> ```
>  private List<NodeInfoBean> getData(Integer parentId) {
>
>       // select id, text from table where parent_id = :parentId
>  }
> ```

4. Write a method to build data:

> ```
>  private List<NodeBean> buildNode(Integer parentId) {
>       List<NodeBean> result = new ArrayList<>();
>       List<NodeInfoBean> data = getData(parentId);
>       for (NodeInfoBean nodeInfo : data){
>            NodeBean node = NodeBean
>                           .builder()
>                           .id(nodeInfo.getId())
>                           .text(nodeInfo.getText())
>                           .children(buildNode(nodeInfo.getId()))
>                           .build();
>            result.add(node);
>       }
>      return result;
> }
> ```

5. In the main, call this method to get result:

> ```
>  List<NodeBean> data = buildNode(null);
>  return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(data);
> ```

6. See the result:

> ```
>   [{
>        "id": 1,
>        "text": "Text1",
>        "children": [
>          {
>            "id": 3,
>            "text": "Text3",
>            "children": []
>          },
>          {
>            "id": 4,
>            "text": "Text4",
>            "children": [
>              {
>                "id": 10,
>                "text": "Text10",
>                "children": []
>              }
>            ]
>          },
>          {
>            "id": 6,
>            "text": "Text6",
>            "children": []
>          }
>  ]},
>   {
>        "id": 2,
>        "text": "Text2",
>         "children": [
>          {
>            "id": 5,
>            "text": "Text5",
>            "children": [
>              {
>                "id": 8,
>                "text": "Text8",
>                "children": []
>              },
>              {
>                "id": 9,
>                "text": "Text9",
>                "children": []
>              }
>            ]
>          }
> ]}]
> ```

Comment: hello, what is '.builder()' ? Does it belong to any kind of library?